# PHP restrict access to superglobals or move the variable data

Tags: php, security, superglobals

The dilemma comes from a plugin system that we are trying to implement security procedures that restrict the plugin to use only the data our system passes to it.

The concern comes from passwords or other sensitive data that may be present in $_POST or other globals.

The initial idea, in an attempt to restrict access to these globals, would be to copy the data, empty the global, and replace it after the plugin is called:

```
$tmpPost = $_POST;
$_POST = [];
pluginCall();
$_POST = $tmpPost;
unset($tmpPost);
```

The problem I foresee is efficiency and memory usage.  What about pages that have large amounts of input data, like file uploads?  We'd be doubling the script memory usage (and I assume adding load time) copying the data to another variable with:

```
$tmpPost = $_POST;
```

So my dilemma and question:

**Is there are way to restrict access to superglobals and/or is there any way to reassign a variable without copying it (essentially a move)?**

Comment: The usual case would rather be that you “trust” your plugins – so what are the circumstances here that make that not a given? Maybe it would rather be an option to let the plugin in a different execution context altogether somehow …? But that might depend on specifics of the system and what job/purpose that plugins are actually supposed to serve.

Comment: what about `file_get_contents('php://input');` ?

Comment: You could set PHP ini to only populate the superglobals when required and then read from an input steam.

Comment: and @AnotherGuy - so could anyone else ( read the input stream ), but can you truncate the input stream? I am not sure of that.

Comment: You could set [**variable_order**](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) to `""`, but for this you would have to use like a `.htaccess` file. So you could put your plugin into a separated folder, put a `.htaccess` file in there and set the `variable_order` to `""`

Comment: As for your memory concerns: PHP uses copy-on-write and and reference counting, so `$tmpPost = $_POST` would not double the memory usage. But I still rather doubt if it is a good idea to “mess” with the superglobals in that way – unexpected side effects might to be expected … (especially with $_FILES I could imagine problems, such as files referenced in there not being recognized as upload files any more after that copying-around operation, or stuff like that.)

Comment: @Rizier123: _“So you could put your plugin into a separated folder, put a .htaccess file in there and set the variable_order to ""”_ – that would not help though, when the plugin is called from within a “main” script outside of the scope of that .htaccess configuration, I think? (Only if the plugin was called directly within its folder via an HTTP request.)

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix - What is your point in the last comment? To me it seems pointless to truncate the input stream anyways.

Comment: my point is, it's pointless to turn of `superglobals` when anyone can read from the raw input stream.  Unless maybe you truncate it, then it's a matter of order.

Comment: The only way is to run the plugin in a different process.

Comment: I'm glad I sparked some conversation last night.  @CBroe the idea is this is a system framework much in the idea of Wordpress, we want users to create third party plugins and we want users to install third party plugins and we want to have a lot of calls on events, but we want to try to protect users from installing malicious third party plugins as much as we can in the code.

Comment: @Gumbo, that wouldn't be the horrible, and you might be right, you have any suggestions on the most efficient way to proceed with this?  I imagine spawning new processes for each plugin call would be rather inefficient.   pthreads, I think would work well, but it not being included in PHP hurts, we want the average shared hosting user to be able to use our system.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, yes that has already been considered.  We are looking at ways of only allowing certain functions inside the plugin as well and allowing plugin creators to only use our filesystem read functions which would restrict them to certain folders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not afraid to take a guess!!

Guessing, but if you moved from $_POST to a system that uses `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, ...)`, you would not even need the superglobal at all (because this function does not use $_POST to get external array sources). You could clear `$_POST` and `filter_input_array()` would get you all the values you need. Then, as you suggest, it really would be up to you to point your plugin to the correct input.

Here is an example from my custom sanitization class. You only need to see this one line and the PHP manual to see what I mean.

```
$_POST = [];

$this->filteredInputArray = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filterDefinition);
```

I have not tried this exact sequence, but it might be worth a shot.